# ERROR: Module php7.4 does not exist! shows

Tags: phpmyadmin, php7

I'm trying to enable php7.4 and disable php8.2,
but I'm not able to enable php7.4, even though php7.4 is already installed

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

please help me with this,
thank you,

Comment: Did you try `apt install libapache2-mod-php` also?